# Multi project setup - No main class detected

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the following simple project setup

```
lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).aggregate(kalosrpc, kalosmodel)

lazy val kalosrpc = project.in(file("kalosrpc")).dependsOn(kalosmodel)

lazy val kalosmodel = project
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      dependencies.slf4j,
      dependencies.slick,
      dependencies.mysql
    )
  )

lazy val kalosgen = project
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      dependencies.slf4j,
      dependencies.slick,
      dependencies.slickCodeGen
    )
  )
```

With the following directory structure

```
|__ api 
   |__ kalosgen
      |__ src
         |__ scala
            |__ Main.scala
   |__ kalosmodel
      |__ src
         |__ scala
            |__ Main.scala
   |__ kalosrpc
      |__ src
         |__ scala
            |__ Main.scala
```

I'm trying to run only the code in `kalosgen`, but when I open the sbt console and do

```
project kalosgen
run
```

I see

```
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
[error]     at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
[error] (Compile / bgRun) No main class detected.
```

Here is the contents of `kalosgen/src/scala/Main.scala`

```
import slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator

object Main extends App {
  val url = "hidden"
  val user = "hidden"
  val password = "hidden"
  val dbDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  val profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile"
  SourceCodeGenerator.main(
    Array(
      profile,
      dbDriver,
      url,
      ".",
      "kalosmodel",
      user,
      password
    )
  )
}
```

As far as I can tell this setup is correct but it won't run and googling the error message has been no help. I've tried using `class` instead of `object` and specifying the main class in the `build.sbt` but nothing is working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`main` subdirectory might be missing from the path. Try changing the structure to

```
kalosgen/src/main/scala/Main.scala
```

instead of

```
kalosgen/src/scala/Main.scala
```